# Sections of a pullback bundle as a pullback itself

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory, manifolds, fiber-bundles

Suppose I have manifolds $Y,Z$ and a bundle $E \to Z$. I want to consider pairs $(\phi,\psi)$, where

- $\phi: Y \to Z$ is a smooth map,
- $\psi: Y \to \phi^*E$ is a section of the pullback of $E$ under $\phi$.

Is the set of such pairs some sort of fiber product? It feels obvious that it is, but I seem to be missing it. In other words, I want a more intrinsic way of writing down the set
$$
\{ (\phi,\psi) \mid \phi \in \mathsf{C}^\infty(Y;Z), \psi \in \Gamma(\phi^*E) \}.
$$
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think this is just $C^\infty(Y; E)$ - if we write the bundle projection as  $\pi : E \to Z,$ then any $f : Y \to E$ can be interpreted as a $\psi$ with $\phi = \pi \circ f$.

Comment: $\phi^*E = Y\times_Z E$ is a fiber product, so a section is just a map $Y\to E$, as mentioned above. (Just restating since OP mentioned fiber products)

Comment: Makes sense to me. Thanks for the help!